# Not able to Install app manually in Device Admin App

Tags: android, android-intent, apk, package-managers, device-admin

I've Device admin app which I want to update by manual installing.The problem is when app is in admin mode I'm not getting the install pop up generated by android to install **apk** but when unpinned or remove app as device admin I am getting that install dialog. I've approached two methods

**First Method** :Install apk using intent

```
        Intent intentInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intentInstall.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Constants.UPDATE_APK_PATH)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        intentInstall.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // without this flag android returned a intent error!
        AppApplication.getContext().startActivity(intentInstall);
```

This method works only when app in not set as device admin

**Second Method** :Silent Install using PackageManger

```
PackageManager packageManger = mContext.getPackageManager();
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            PackageInstaller packageInstaller = packageManger.getPackageInstaller();
            String packageName = mContext.getPackageName();
            PackageInstaller.SessionParams params = new PackageInstaller.SessionParams(
                    PackageInstaller.SessionParams.MODE_FULL_INSTALL);
            params.setAppPackageName(packageName);
            try {
                int sessionId = packageInstaller.createSession(params);
                PackageInstaller.Session session = packageInstaller.openSession(sessionId);
                OutputStream out = session.openWrite(packageName + ".apk", 0, -1);
                readTo(Constants.UPDATE_APK_PATH, out); //read the apk content and write it to out
                session.fsync(out);
                out.close();
                System.out.println("installing...");
                session.commit(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, sessionId,
                        new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN"), 0).getIntentSender());
                System.out.println("install request sent");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.err.println("old sdk");*/

private static void readTo(String updateApkPath, OutputStream out) {
        try {
            File file = new File(updateApkPath);
            out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            out.flush();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I did little research for package manger and came across this solution but this does not work in my case

In short I want to update my device admin app by manual install.

Any help will be appreciated